# How to display element when hovering another element and maintain this hover styling when hovering the new element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling with the structure of my HTML elements: I hover an image that makes a second image (class=look_block) overlap the main image (class=looks) with the hover animation, buttons (class=quick-add) appear as well; When I hover these buttons all the changes made while hovering the main image revert and the button itself disappears. I attempted to apply the same hover animations to the button that appears to maintain styling but it refuses to communicate with the elements.

**[This is my website for reference...](https://azuretec.us) *(the hover animation is placed on each of the images in the image gallery at the bottom of the page)***

When hovering the button I expect the changes made when hovering the image to be maintained,

```css
.looks:hover {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.quick-add:hover+.look_block {
  position: absolute;
}

.quick-add:hover+.look_block {
  display: block !important;
}

.quick-add:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-top: -1% !important;
}

.looks:hover+.quick-add {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-top: -1% !important;
}

.looks:hover+.look_block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="looks_reel" style="display:grid;">
    <div>
    <div class="look_block"><img alt="Super Cat Bed Warm Sleeping Cat Nest Soft Long Pluh Best Pet Dog Bed For Dogs Basket Cushion Cat Bed Cat Mat Animals Sleeping So" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S9c1b79c0b59442d0b36ea6aea9cd266fO/Super-Cat-Bed-Warm-Sleeping-Cat-Nest-Soft-Long-Pluh-Best-Pet-Dog-Bed-For-Dogs.jpg.jpg" style="width: auto; height: auto;" id="look_1"></div>
    <div><i class="large material-icons">forward</i></div>
    <img class="looks" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0645/6842/6713/files/8_banner.png?v=1656016078" alt="" width="17%">
    <div class="quick-add" style="opacity: 0; top: 114%; right: 78.8%; position: absolute; width: 16.5% !important;">
    <modal-opener data-modal="#QuickAdd-7687876215001">
                    <button id="quick-add-template--16036884447449__product-grid7687876215001-submit" type="submit" name="add" class="quick-add__submit button button--full-width button--secondary" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-labelledby="quick-add-template--16036884447449__product-grid7687876215001-submit title-template--16036884447449__product-grid-7687876215001" data-product-url="/products/propeller-shower-head">
                      Choose options
                      <div class="loading-overlay__spinner hidden">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="spinner" viewbox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </modal-opener>
                  </div>
    </div>
```

when not hovering image:
[image: image 1]
when hovering image:
[image: image 2]
when hovering button:
[image: image 3]

Comment: are you trying to make the button appear top of the changes image ?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, so we could play around with it?

Comment: yes, all the changes go away when I hover the button, the button would go away itself but I added in a hover animation for the button that would make it stay there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=SPkM8243cC    (Basically when hovering the first image, if you hover the button that appears everything goes crazy and the changes attempt to revert themselves because I am technically not hovering the image anymore (that applies all the changes through :hover)) CSS Styling is at the top of the HTML

Comment: Is Faizal's answer working for you?

Comment: no, I am working on adding some javascript (onmouseover), I believe this will be the solution.

Comment: Excuse me, the exact goal is unclear to me. I have opened your fiddle and hovered on items. An image with the text of "forward" appears on each hover, while a popup of choose options animates from bottom-left to the top-left of the page. I understand this is incorrect, hence your question. What should happen instead?

Comment: the button appears when hovering the first image, hover over that button and the image reappears but the button stays, I need the second image to be there rather the main image reappearing when hovering the button. This is because the hover animation (the animation that makes the button and the second image appear) is hooked up to the main image, when I hover over the button I am technically no longer hovering the main image and all the styling applied through the hover animation on the main image disappears, hence the main image reappears when hovering the button.

Comment: I have applied hover animations to the button that make it stay there , it would usually disappear. "function display_buttons() document.getElementById("image_1").style.display = "none";}" with a mouseover event I have managed to make the image disappear, I added the id, "image_1" to the main image and a onmouseover event ("display_buttons()") to my button. Still not a perfect fix though, working through it. Only issue I have with this javascript fix is the styling applies directly to the html element and will remain there as if I were to manually edit an element through the chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that the div containing the button is absolutely positioned, when an element is absolutely positioned it can move freely inside the relative parent  ( using top bottom right and left )  but the issue here is the parent div is not relatively positioned, so the absolutely child will move towards the next parent with relative positioning, to fix this add position to parent and adjust top left right of the absolute child accordingly

```
<div style="
    position: relative;
">
<div class="look_block" style="
    /* position: relative; */
"><img alt="Super Cat Bed Warm Sleeping Cat Nest Soft Long Pluh Best Pet Dog Bed For Dogs Basket Cushion Cat Bed Cat Mat Animals Sleeping So" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S9c1b79c0b59442d0b36ea6aea9cd266fO/Super-Cat-Bed-Warm-Sleeping-Cat-Nest-Soft-Long-Pluh-Best-Pet-Dog-Bed-For-Dogs.jpg.jpg" style="width: auto; height: auto;" id="look_1"></div>
<div><i class="large material-icons">forward</i></div>
<img class="looks" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0645/6842/6713/files/12_border.png?v=1656026758" alt="" width="17%">
<div class="quick-add" style="opacity: 0;top: 40%;right: 20.8%;position: absolute;/* width: 16.5% !important; */">
<modal-opener data-modal="#QuickAdd-7687876215001">
                <button id="quick-add-template--16036884447449__product-grid7687876215001-submit" type="submit" name="add" class="quick-add__submit button button--full-width button--secondary" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-labelledby="quick-add-template--16036884447449__product-grid7687876215001-submit title-template--16036884447449__product-grid-7687876215001" data-product-url="/products/propeller-shower-head">
                  Choose options
                  <div class="loading-overlay__spinner hidden">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                      <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </modal-opener>
              </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesnt change anything regarding to the styling disappearing, the animation is much cleaner though! Everything still disappears when hovering the button because I am not technically hovering the main image that makes the button appear when I hover the button. I am working on adding some javascript (onmouseover), I believe this will be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here the structure is most important:

```html
<div class="items">
          <img src="">
          <button>choose option</button>
          <img src="" class="hovered-img">
        </div>
```

We have kept button in middle of two images.
`.hovered-img` this image we set absolute and first set it's `opacity:0`.
-Now,`items` class gets `:hover` we set `.hovered-img` to `opacity:1`.

- For button, by default we set it's `opacity:0; visibility:hidden;`, however, when `:hover` applied to `items` we set `opacity:1; visibility:visible;`.
- As we set `button` before `.hovered-img` we can select it using `~` selctor, **which select next sibling irrespective of there type.**

> `.items:hover button:hover~.hovered-img` This line says that, hey please apply this styles to `hovered-img` when `items` is hovered and `button` is also hovered.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.items {
  flex: 1 0 calc(100%/3);
  position: relative;
}

.items img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.items .hovered-img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.items button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 9;
}

.items:hover .hovered-img {
  opacity: 1
}

.items:hover button {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.items:hover button:hover~.hovered-img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="items">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="default-img">
      <button>choose option</button>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656068697133-e7c0ef2e861e?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY1NzkwMDE5MA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" class="hovered-img">
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="default-img">
      <button>choose option</button>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656068697133-e7c0ef2e861e?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY1NzkwMDE5MA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" class="hovered-img">
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="default-img">
      <button>choose option</button>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656068697133-e7c0ef2e861e?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY1NzkwMDE5MA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" class="hovered-img">
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="default-img">
      <button>choose option</button>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656068697133-e7c0ef2e861e?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY1NzkwMDE5MA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" class="hovered-img">
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="default-img">
      <button>choose option</button>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656068697133-e7c0ef2e861e?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY1NzkwMDE5MA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" class="hovered-img">
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="default-img">
      <button>choose option</button>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656068697133-e7c0ef2e861e?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY1NzkwMDE5MA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" class="hovered-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran the code and it actually is better to work with than the fiddle url I shared. This emulates the issue I am running into. Hover the image and you see a button and a new image, hover that button and the first image reappears. I believe javascript would help here: function display_buttons() document.getElementById("image_1").style.display = "none";}. If you gave unique ids (image_1 being the first main image in the grid) to each of the main images and made a function for each this would maintain the styling but the change would be permenant. New to Java/HTML/CSS so bear with me haha

Answer (score 0):

Added onmouseout to my main image (id=image1) and a onmouseover event to my button (id=add1). Javascript was the solution, the images now correctly overlay eachother, it works perfectly as a permanent solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<div class="look_block"><img alt="Super Cat Bed Warm Sleeping Cat Nest Soft Long Pluh Best Pet Dog Bed For Dogs Basket Cushion Cat Bed Cat Mat Animals Sleeping So" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S9c1b79c0b59442d0b36ea6aea9cd266fO/Super-Cat-Bed-Warm-Sleeping-Cat-Nest-Soft-Long-Pluh-Best-Pet-Dog-Bed-For-Dogs.jpg.jpg" style="width: auto; height: auto;" id="look_1"></div>
<div><i class="large material-icons">forward</i></div>
<img id="image1" onmouseout="hovering_done(this)" class="looks" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0645/6842/6713/files/8_banner.png?v=1656016078" alt="" width="17%" style="opacity: 1;">
<div id="add1" class="quick-add" onmouseover="hovering_current(this)" style="opacity: 0; top: 114%; right: 78.8%; position: absolute; width: 16.5% !important;">
<modal-opener data-modal="#QuickAdd-7687876215001">
                <button id="quick-add-template--16036884447449__product-grid7687876215001-submit" type="submit" name="add" class="quick-add__submit button button--full-width button--secondary" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-labelledby="quick-add-template--16036884447449__product-grid7687876215001-submit title-template--16036884447449__product-grid-7687876215001" data-product-url="/products/propeller-shower-head">
                  Choose options
                  <div class="loading-overlay__spinner hidden">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                      <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </modal-opener>
              </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function hovering_current(ele) {
  document.getElementById("image" + (ele.id.match(/\d/g)).join("")).style.opacity = "0";
}
function hovering_done(ele) {
  ele.style.opacity = "1";
}
```